# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.

Tags: android, sql

I'm having an issue with a java.lang.IllegalStateException in a part of my code. I've read some of the previous answers etc, but nothing seems to be working.

this is my code:

```
    highFreqWord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.freqWord);
    //Instantiate database connection
    mydb = new DBHelper(this);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    Log.d("extraKDJFSKDF", String.valueOf(extras));
    //If there is extras a contact has been selected. If not we are processing an Add Contact request from the main menu
    if(extras !=null)
    {
        Log.d("Hit,", "id");
        int value = extras.getInt("id");
        Log.d("extraKDJFSKDF", String.valueOf(extras));
        Log.d("id", String.valueOf(value));
        if(value>0){
            //Retrieve the data back from the database for the selected contact
            Cursor rs = mydb.getData(value);
            id_To_Update = value;
            //Move to first item in query result from mydb.getData() method
            rs.moveToFirst();
            Log.d("Hit ","1");
            //Setting string values to appropriate data in database result (rs)
            String freqUsedWord = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.FREQ_WORD));
            if (!rs.isClosed())
            {
                rs.close();
            }
```

and the error i'm getting:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ltssdyslexiaapp/com.example.ltss.dyslexia.app.FreqWordsPage}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my DBHelper code for creating the table:

```
String CREATE_FREQ_WORDS_TABLE  = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FREQ_WORDS  + "("
            + FREQ_WORD_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + FREQ_WORD  + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_FREQ_WORDS_TABLE);
```

I've tried everything I can think of, but to no avail - is there any way to get a more useful error?

Any advice would be much appreciated.Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind - It turned out that I was calling the incorrect getData cursor. Once that was fixed and the app was re-installed, it started working fine

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake, you have to initialize highFreqWord as a textview first before assigning it.

```
Textview highFreqWord = (Textview) findViewbyId(R.idfreqWord);
```

Comment: already have it set as a TextView above (it's declared at the top of the program, don't have it pasted in here)

Comment: could you post more of your db helper code, I can't see any mistakes in the code posted